# How .Net CLR deals with memory returned from P/Invoke call?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a .Net 4.6 C# GUI app that uses a native DLL. I would like to process data in the native code and return memory allocated on the native side back to C#.

I've read various questions on StackOverflow and links from around the web but there are some missing pieces I want to ensure, and potentially gather all the relevant interop answers in one place.

**Case 1:**

```cs
[DllImport("Native.dll")]
public static extern void GetStringA(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    out string str);
```

- This one as I understand from the following documentation will be copied first and the original buffer will be freed using `CoTaskMemFree`.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices
> **Windows Specific** For `[Out]` strings the CLR will use `CoTaskMemFree` by default to free strings or `SysStringFree` for strings that are marked as `UnmanagedType.BSTR`.

**Case 2:**

```cs
[DllImport("Native.dll")]
public static extern void GetStringW(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    out string str);
```

- Will CLR call `CoTaskMemFree` on `str` or is it going to use the existing buffer and call `CoTaskMemFree` on a later GC cycle?
  (Notice the `LPWStr`)

**Case 3:**

```cs
[DllImport("Native.dll")]
public static extern void GetStringA(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    out string str,
    out int length);
```

- Will CLR take `SizeParamIndex` into account while marshalling back or just look for null termination?

**Case 4:**

```cs
[DllImport("Native.dll")]
public static extern void GetInts(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    out int[] array,
    out int length);
```

- Will CLR call `CoTaskMemFree` on `array` or is it going to use the existing buffer and call `CoTaskMemFree` on a later GC cycle? Documentation talks about `CoTaskMem*` functions for strings but I couldn't see info on whether it handles `LPArray` the same way.
- Will CLR take `SizeParamIndex` into account here while marshalling back or is it only effective for input parameters?

**Case 5:**

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string str;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    public int[] ints;
}

[DllImport("Native.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void GetStructs(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    out MyStruct[] array,
    out int length);
```

- Can I count on CLR to handle complex types properly the same way it handles simple types?
  Is it going to recursively marshal and copy/reuse reference types the way I naturally expect?

---

TLDR; how do I handle memory management & ownership fully correct while using native interop? (FYI I author the native DLL as well as the GUI app.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1:**

The key point you are missing is the docuementation for `CoTaskMemFree`

> Frees a block of task memory **previously allocated through** a call to the `CoTaskMemAlloc` or `CoTaskMemRealloc` function.

If your function does not allocate strings that way (for example it uses `new` or `malloc`) then the memory does not get freed and will leak. You ***must*** make sure to free the memory buffer using the same mechanism that is used to allocate it.

The marshaller does not magically know what allocation strategy you used. Ideally your C++ code would provide a `FreeMemory` function.

**Case 2:**

`CoTaskMemFree` is called immediately on the return of the function, after the pointer is copied into the `out string`. The marshaller does not get involved at all once your function has finished.

**Case 3:**

As far as I am aware, `SizeParamIndex` is only used for arrays, not strings, so null-termination will be used. Instead you can marshal this as a `byte[]` and copy it out afterwards.

```cs
[DllImport("Native.dll")]
public static extern void GetStringA(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    out byte[] str,
    out int length);
```

**Case 4:**

No, the marshaller will not free the array at all. You need to free the array yourself.

**Case 5:**

Yes, the marshaller will handle nested structs. But there are some things that cannot be done. For example, `SizeParamIndex` doe not work on struct members or on arrays inside structs. `SizeConst` still works, as does `LPArray`.

I suggest you specify the `CharSet` in your specific example.

---

**I would suggest firstly,** that you reconsider the reasons you are using C++ in the first place, and whether it is possible to write that code in C#.

**Secondly,** if possible use `BSTR` and `SAFEARRAY`, both of which the marshaller can fully handle in all cases, including nested arrays and arrays of strings.

If that is not possible, always try to allocate array buffers from C# and pass them in as `[Out]` parameters, as then the marshaller can allocate an unmanaged buffer (or pin it if blittable) in order for C++ to write into. The marshaller will copy and free (or unpin) that buffer automatically

Comment: As I understand it, (1) out strings are copied back regardless of being [blittable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types). (2) Generic arrays will reuse the returned buffer (if blittable) and CLR will not attempt to manage it whatsoever. (3) `SizeParamIndex` works in both (in/out) directions. Anything wrong with my understanding? Also what about non-blittable `LPArray`, how do I even free the original array if CLR gives me a copy of it without cleaning up the original?

Comment: 1. Yes they are copied, but are not freed unless they were allocated using `CoTaskMemAlloc`. 2. Correct, arrays are not managed (except `SAFEARRAY`). 3. `SizeParamIndex` I believe so. 4. Generally, you would allocate a buffer of an array on the C# side, pass that in as an `[Out]` parameter, and the marshaller will allocate an unmanaged buffer for the C++ to copy into, which it then frees after copying back. See edit.